# What do i have to change on the server side to enable chunkedMode = true?

Tags: php, javascript, android, cordova

I am currently working on an Android app made with the PhoneGap framework. The app captures a video which is uploaded to a server. I used to set the chunkedMode to FALSE, and for files smaller than 10MB everything works fine. For files bigger than 10MB I get an Out of Memory Exception. To fix that I changed to chunkedMode = true, but right now I always get an connection error (error code 3).

Do I have the change something on the server to accept the chunked mode?

The server is an CentOS server with Apache 2/HTTP 1.1. I use the following line in the PHP (server side) script:

`move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target)`

I really hope someone can help me with this problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First thing to check is what your max upload size is in your php.ini file:

```
upload_max_filesize = 10M
```

If you are not using PHP5 you will need to upgrade as PHP4 does not support chunked mode.

As far as I know most Apache web severs already have chunked mode turned on. One dev was using Nginx as a web server and had to install this module.

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpChunkinModule

Mind you there wiki seems to be down right now.

Comment: Hi Simon,

I am using PHP Version 5.3.10. The upload_max_filesize is set to 16M. When I turn on the ChunkedMode the error even occurs when I try to upload a file of 1MB.

Comment: I can show you the phpinfo() if that helps you to identify the problem

Comment: I don't think it is a PHP problem then. What webserver are you running?

Comment: Server version: Apache/2.2.22

Comment: I'm using Server version: Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) and it seems to be on by default.

Comment: I'm still having the same problems, but only on Android. I've spent the last months on working on the iOS app and on that OS everything works fine with the chunkedMode set to true. I switched from my own server to Amazon s3 cloud storage so the server settings shouldn't be the problem.

When I use the exact example code it works fine on iOS but on multiple Android devices I receive the following errors:

Comment: 06-20 18:33:08.701: E/FileTransfer(664): Broken pipe
06-20 18:33:08.701: E/FileTransfer(664): java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
06-20 18:33:08.701: E/FileTransfer(664):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.sendStreamImpl(Native Method)
06-20 18:33:08.701: E/FileTransfer(664):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.sendStream(OSNetworkSystem.java:498)
06-20 18:33:08.701: E/FileTransfer(664):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:585)

Comment: 06-20 18:33:08.701: E/FileTransfer(664):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:50)
06-20 18:33:08.701: E/FileTransfer(664):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpOutputStream.write(HttpURLConnection.java:652)
06-20 18:33:08.701: E/FileTransfer(664):  at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:101)
06-20 18:33:08.701: E/FileTransfer(664):  at org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer.upload(FileTransfer.java:358)

Comment: 06-20 18:33:08.701: E/FileTransfer(664):  at org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer.execute(FileTransfer.java:98)
06-20 18:33:08.701: E/FileTransfer(664):  at org.apache.cordova.api.PluginManager$1.run(PluginManager.java:186)
06-20 18:33:08.701: E/FileTransfer(664):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1102)